# EmployeeManager output errors

Tags: java

For a Java II class of mine, we are doing an assignment for making a program, EmployeeManager, to work with a test program plus 4 .class programs that the instructor provides. However, I'm experiencing some issues with getting the proper output.

```
public class mcshonsey_EmployeeManager
{
final int EMPLOYEE_MAX = 15;
Employee[] employees = new Employee[EMPLOYEE_MAX];
int currentEmployees;

public mcshonsey_EmployeeManager()
{
    employees = new Employee[this.getEmployeeMax()];
    currentEmployees = 0;
}

public int getEmployeeMax()
{
    return this.EMPLOYEE_MAX;
}

public void setCurrentEmployees(int currentEmployees)
{
    this.currentEmployees = currentEmployees;
}

public int getCurrentEmployees()
{
    return this.currentEmployees;
}

public void addEmployee(int type, String firstName, String lastName, char mI, char gender, int employeeNumber, boolean fulltime, double amount)
{
    if (this.getCurrentEmployees() < 15);
    {
        setCurrentEmployees(getCurrentEmployees() + 1);
    }

    if (this.getCurrentEmployees() == 15);
    {
        System.out.println("Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee " + employeeNumber + " not added. ");
    }


    if (type == 1)
    {
        employees[this.getCurrentEmployees()] = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, mI, gender, employeeNumber, fulltime, amount);
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        employees[this.getCurrentEmployees()] = new SalaryEmployee(firstName, lastName, mI, gender, employeeNumber, fulltime, amount);
    }
    else
    {
        employees[this.getCurrentEmployees()] = new CommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, mI, gender, employeeNumber, fulltime, amount);
    }
}

public void removeEmployee(int index)
{
    do
    {
        employees[index] = employees[14];
        this.currentEmployees = currentEmployees;
        currentEmployees += -1;
    } while (index <= this.currentEmployees);
}

public void listAll()
{
    if (this.currentEmployees == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("None \n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
        {
            if (employees[x] != null)
            {
                System.out.println(employees[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void listHourly()
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
        {
            if (employees[x] instanceof HourlyEmployee)
            {
                a += 1;
                System.out.println(employees[x]);
            }
        }

            if (a == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("None \n");
            }
    }

public void listSalary()
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
      {
            if (employees[x] instanceof SalaryEmployee)
            {
                a += 1;
                System.out.println(employees[x]);
            }
      }

            if (a == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("None \n");
            }
    }

public void listCommission()
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < employees.length; x++)
        {
            if (employees[x] instanceof CommissionEmployee)
            {
                a += 1;
                System.out.println(employees[x]);
            }
        }

        if (a == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("None \n");
        }
    }

public void resetWeek()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        employees[x].resetWeek();
    }
}

public double calculatePayout()
{
    double totalPay = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;

    for (int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        y = employees[x].calculateWeeklyPay();
        totalPay += y;
    }

    return totalPay;
}

public void removeRedundancies()
{

}

public int getIndex(int employeeNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    int y;

    for (int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        y = employees[x].getEmployeeNumber();

        if (y == employeeNumber)
        {
            index = x;
            x = 1000;
        }

        else
        {
            index = -1;
        }
    }

    return index;
}

public void sortNumber()
{
    Employee[] employees2 = new Employee[1];
    int aindex;
    int bindex;

    int [] employeeNumbers = new int[currentEmployees];
    boolean flag = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        employeeNumbers[x] = employees[x].getEmployeeNumber();
    }

    while(flag)
    {
        flag = false;
        int temporary;

        for (int b = 0; b < currentEmployees; b++)
        {
            if (employeeNumbers[b] > employeeNumbers[b+1])
            {
                temporary = employeeNumbers[b];
                employeeNumbers[b] = employeeNumbers[b+1];
                employeeNumbers[b+1] = temporary;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < currentEmployees; b++)
    {
        aindex = getIndex(employeeNumbers[b]);
        bindex = b;

        employees2[0] = employees[b];
        employees[b] = employees[aindex];
        employees[aindex] = employees2[0];
    }
}
public void sortName()
{
    Employee[] employee2 = new Employee[1];
    int aindex;
    int bindex;

    String [] names = new String[currentEmployees];
    for (int b = 0; b < currentEmployees; b++)
    {
        for (int c = b + 1; c < currentEmployees; c++)
        {
            if (employees[c].getLastName().compareTo(employees[b].getLastName()) < 0)
            {
                employee2[0] = employees[b];
                employees[b] = employees[c];
                employees[c] = employee2[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

public void annualRaise()
{

    for(int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        employees[x].annualRaise();
    }
}

public double holidayBonuses()
{
    double bonus = 0.0;

    for (int x = 0; x < currentEmployees; x++)
    {
        bonus += employees[x].holidayBonus();
    }
    return bonus;
}

public void increaseHours(int index, double amount)
{
    for (Employee currentEmployees: employees)
    {
        if (currentEmployees instanceof HourlyEmployee)
        {
            ((HourlyEmployee) employees[index]).increaseHours(amount);
        }
    }
}

public void increaseSales(int index, double amount)
{
    for (Employee currentEmployees: employees)
    {
        if (currentEmployees instanceof CommissionEmployee)
        {
            ((CommissionEmployee) employees[index]).increaseSales(amount);
        }
    }
}                                                                           }
```

Now, the code compiles fine, and runs as well. But, running it produces this:

```
   List of all employees, HourlyEmployees, SalaryEmployees and   CommissionEmployees:
 None
 None
 None
 None

 Adding employees. . .
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 35487 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 18224 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 68176 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 87995 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 54145 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 35487 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 18224 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 98573 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 83574 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 90842 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 72108 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 35487 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 18224 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 68176 not added.
 Maximum number of Employees reached. Employee 43872 not added.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
    at mcshonsey_EmployeeManager.addEmployee  (mcshonsey_EmployeeManager.java:64)
    at EmployeeManagerTest.main(EmployeeManagerTest.java:79)
```

(NEW OUTPUT)

Which, is not the right output. None is only supposed to appear 4 times before moving to adding employees, should only list one employee to not be added.

I'm really stumped at how to fix this to get it to work properly. How to I fix this?

EDIT: Line 64, where the error is shown to happen, is this:

```
 employees[this.getCurrentEmployees()] = new SalaryEmployee(firstName, lastName, mI, gender, employeeNumber, fulltime, amount);
```

EDIT again: Here's the main() method, EmployeeManagerTest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  



// To display currency correctly  

import java.text.NumberFormat;  



// To get current locale  

import java.util.Locale;  



public class EmployeeManagerTest  

{  

public static void main(String[] args)  

{  

    // Variable declarations  

     mcshonsey_EmployeeManager em =          // An EmployeManager object  

                              new mcshonsey_EmployeeManager();  



   Locale currentLocale =              // Store current locale  

                           Locale.getDefault();  



     NumberFormat currencyFormatter =    // Currency formatter  

                           NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);  



   // Display all employees, HourlyEmployees, SalaryEmployees and  

   // CommissionEmployees  

    System.out.println("List of all employees, HourlyEmployees, " +  

                      "SalaryEmployees and CommissionEmployees:");  

   em.listAll();  

    em.listHourly();  

   em.listSalary();  

    em.listCommission();  



    // Add employees  

    // Random names generated at http://random-name-generator.info  

 // Random employee numbers generated at http://random.org  

   // For more rigorous tests, uncomment the adds below.  
    System.out.println("\nAdding employees. . .");  

   em.addEmployee(1, "Florence", "Copeland", 'F', 'F', 35487, true, 10);  

    em.addEmployee(3, "Jacqueline", "Newton", 'G', 'F', 18224, false, 1);  

   em.addEmployee(2, "Norma", "Flowers", 'E', 'F', 68176, false, 10000);  

    em.addEmployee(1, "Marian", "Moran", 'T', 'F', 87995, false, 20);  

   em.addEmployee(3, "Anna", "Jacobs", 'F', 'F', 54145, true, 2);  



    // The next two employees are duplicates of the first and second  

    // (employees are equal if their employeeNumbers are the same).  

   em.addEmployee(2, "Eloise", "Franklin", 'I', 'F', 35487, true, 40000);  

    em.addEmployee(1, "Edwin", "Tyler", 'J', 'M', 18224, false, 10);  



                 em.addEmployee(1, "Jamie", "Lamb", 'O', 'F', 98573, false, 30);  

  em.addEmployee(2, "Donnie", "Hogan", 'Q', 'M', 83574, false, 30000);  

     em.addEmployee(1, "Dennis", "Andrews", 'G', 'M', 90842, false, 40);  

    em.addEmployee(1, "Sherry", "Rowe", 'U', 'F', 72108, true, 50);  



    // em.addEmployee(3, "Delia", "Hunter", 'C', 'F', 13695, true, 4);  

    // em.addEmployee(2, "Yvonne", "Douglas", 'D', 'F', 88511, false,       50000);  

    // em.addEmployee(3, "Alonzo", "Welch", 'O', 'M', 18088, false, 5);  

    // em.addEmployee(3, "Gregory", "Tate", 'C', 'M', 97772, true, 1);  

    // em.addEmployee(1, "Sally", "Mendoza", 'D', 'F', 52896, true, 20);  

   // em.addEmployee(3, "Ellis", "Adams", 'G', 'M', 77332, false, 2);  

    // em.addEmployee(3, "Clifford", "Lindsey", 'D', 'M', 39033, false, 3);  

    // em.addEmployee(2, "Kristy", "Morales", 'O', 'F', 51171, true, 10000);  

    // em.addEmployee(3, "Rudy", "Cobb", 'Q', 'F', 65485, true, 4);  



    // The next three employees are duplicates of the first, second, and    third  

    // (employees are equal if their employeeNumbers are the same).  

     em.addEmployee(2, "Johnnie", "Maldonado", 'R', 'M', 35487, true, 20000);  

    em.addEmployee(3, "Andre", "Graham", 'C', 'M', 18224, false, 5);  

     em.addEmployee(1, "Dwayne", "Watts", 'E', 'M', 68176, true, 30);  



          em.addEmployee(2, "Susie", "Barker", 'L', 'F', 43872, true, 20000);  

   em.addEmployee(3, "Nora", "Lucas", 'L', 'F', 35764, true, 3);  



    // Display all employees  

    System.out.println("\nList of all employees:");  

     em.listAll();  



    // Remove redundancies and display  

   System.out.println("\nRemoving redundancies. . .");  

     em.removeRedundancies();  

  System.out.println("\nList of all employees after removing redundancies:");  

   em.listAll();  



    // Display just the HourlyEmployees, SalaryEmployees and                CommissionEmployees  

    System.out.println("\nList of HourlyEmployees:");  

    em.listHourly();  

    System.out.println("\nList of SalaryEmployees:");  

   em.listSalary();  

     System.out.println("\nList of CommissionEmployees:");  

   em.listCommission();  



    // Sort by employee number and display  

   System.out.println("\nSorting by employee number. . .");  

    em.sortNumber();  

   em.listAll();  



   // Sort by last name and display  

  System.out.println("\nSorting by last name. . .");  

    em.sortName();  

   em.listAll();  



   // Calculate and display total weekly payout  

    System.out.printf("\nTotal weekly payout: %s.\n",  

                     currencyFormatter.format(em.calculatePayout()));  



   // Get the index of an employee that doesn't exist  

    System.out.printf("\nIndex of employee with employee number 11111:      %d\n",  

                    em.getIndex(11111));  



     // Attempt to increase hours (can only be applied to HourlyEmployees)  

   System.out.println("\nIncreasing hours. . .");  

   em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(35487), 40);  

     em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(18224), 40);  

  em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(68176), 40);  

    em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(87995), 40);  

   em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(54145), 40);  

    em.increaseHours(em.getIndex(43872), 40);  



   // Attempt to increase sales (can only be applied to                    CommissionEmployees)  

  System.out.println("Increasing sales. . .");  
  em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(35487), 40);  

    em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(18224), 40);  

    em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(68176), 40);  

   em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(87995), 40);  

   em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(54145), 40);  

  em.increaseSales(em.getIndex(43872), 40);  



     // Calculate and display total weekly payout after increases  

    System.out.printf("\nTotal weekly payout after increases: %s.\n",  

                      currencyFormatter.format(em.calculatePayout()));  



    // Give four years of annual raises.  

    System.out.println("\nGiving four years of annual raises. . .");  

   em.annualRaise();  

     em.annualRaise();  

    em.annualRaise();  

    em.annualRaise();  



    // Calculate and display total weekly payout after raises  

   System.out.printf("\nTotal weekly payout after raises: %s.\n",  

                      currencyFormatter.format(em.calculatePayout()));  

   // Calculate and display holiday bonus  

   System.out.printf("\nHoliday bonuses: %s.\n",  
                  currencyFormatter.format(em.holidayBonuses()));  



    // Reset weeks  

   System.out.println("\nResetting the weeks. . .");  

   em.resetWeek();  



    // Calculate and display total weekly payout  

    System.out.printf("\nTotal weekly payout after reset: %s.\n",  

                     currencyFormatter.format(em.calculatePayout()));  

 } // End main()  

} // End class
```

EDIT again: My instructor gave a couple recommendations for some fixes, and I've updated the code and output it gives now.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the Test program to compile and run the program. All I can tell is that the problem seems to be in addemployee, and possibly all 4 of the list() methods.

Comment: Are you running the right class file?